# Ubuntu-Apache: How to start automatically apache at boot?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, zend-server

I have zend server. So I tried to make an option in System->Preferences->Sessions
Added /usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh. 
Also tried /usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh start-apache and /usr/local/zend/bin/sh zendctl.sh start-apache.
Nothing started.
The same is for MySQL - doesn't started also.

Any ideas how to make autorun for these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove  your start up application entry which you stated above.

Below solution would be fine if you can start your zend server with:

**sudo /usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh start-apache**

if your server can be started by the command, then process

open **/etc/init.d/rc.local** using your favorite text editor (with super-user privilege)

e.g.

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/rc.local
```

append your start up command at the end of the file,then save & exit & reboot

```
/usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh start-apache
```